# Initializer list, parameter pack expansion, fold expressions and order of evaluation

Tags: c++, c++17, initializer-list, fold-expression, parameter-pack

I have the following code to address a n-dimensional tensor class (offset is a std::vector of std::size_t):

```
template <typename ...Ts>
double Tensor::at(int first, Ts... others) {
    int i = 0;
    std::size_t index = static_cast<std::size_t>(first)*_offset[0];
    (void)std::initializer_list<int>{(index += _offset[++i]*static_cast<std::size_t>(others), 0)...};
    return _data[index];
}
```

This works but I have some questions since I wrote this code by piecing lots of information I found online.

1. The first one is what exactly is happening at line 5 and the correct name for it. If I am not wrong this should unpack the expression and create a braced-init-list[*]. Each element of this list is itself a comma-separated list in the form (exp,0)[**]. The expansion should therefore be {(exp1,0),...(expn,0)}. Am I right?
2. The second one is about the evaluation order. [**] should be only useful to provide a return value to the constructor of the inizialier_list and not serve other purposes (even if index could be itself the return value?). [*] instead, gives an order to the evaluation of the expression. I found it in the example of a print function:

```
(void)std::initializer_list<int>{(print(others),0)...};
```

so that print is called in order on the parameters. Is this also true for composed expressions?:

```
(void)std::initializer_list<int>{(print(compute(others)),0)...};
```

so that if "compute" depends on a state, this is updated according to the order of the parameters leading to always the same results (independently of compiler ecc...). In the tensor example this refers to the ++i.

3. The last question refers to [this](https://articles.emptycrate.com/2016/05/14/folds_in_cpp11_ish.html) , in which the use of += in the way did for the tensors is called fold expression. I don't think this is the case. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your understanding is correct.

2. I'm not sure what you mean by "composed expressions", etc, but yes, initializers in braces are always evaluated left-to-right. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> 10. In list-initialization, every value computation and side effect of a given initializer clause is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any initializer clause that follows it in the brace-enclosed comma-separated list of initalizers.

3. This is not a fold expression. A [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) must have one of the following forms:

- `( pack op ... )`
- `( ... op pack )`
- `( pack op ... op init )`
- `( init op ... op pack )`

Where `op` is a binary operator (most of them are allowed), `pack` is an expression containing at least one unexpanded parameter pack (`Ts` or `others` in your case), `init` is just a normal expression, and `...` must be present literally.

Your function can be simplified using a fold expression. Instead of:

```
(void)std::initializer_list<int>{(index += _offset[++i]*static_cast<std::size_t>(others), 0)...};
```

you can write:

```
((index += _offset[++i]*static_cast<std::size_t>(others)), ...);
```